# How would I pass an object to a new activity, modify that object, and update the changes in the first activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a sort of Idle RPG game in Android Studio. You have a Hero that has some attributes like XP, level, health, gold etc.

I have the main screen where the name, XP and level is displayed. Then I would like to open another activity and change the XP, and when I go back to the first screen the XP would also be updated there.

How would I go about doing this?

I got it to work by making the Hero object a Singleton. However, this gives me some design problems further down the line, so I would prefer to use an alternative method.

I have also tried passing the object using intents, but it doesn't seem to be updating the changes in the main activity. So far, it just updates the object's attributes in the second activity, but when I close that activity none of the changes will be saved - even when I open the activity again.

I am not very experienced with developing Android Apps, so I am probably doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("hero", hero);
        startActivity(intent);
```

```
Hero hero = (Hero) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("hero");
hero.incxp();
```

Comment: You don't pass objects like this between Activities, you should have a data layer, a class such as DataContext where you store objects to me modified, then Activities can read the objects from this DataContext class

Answer (score 2):

You should use startActivityForResult to send your object to the second Activity. After updating your values in the second activity pass back the object to the first Activity and use it to update your values.
In First Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("hero", hero);
    startActivityForResult(intent,101);
```

In Second Activity:

```
Hero hero = (Hero) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("hero");
hero.incxp();
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("hero",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Again back in First Activity, override your onActivityResultMethod to get back the value:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == 101) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Hero hero = (Hero) data.getSerializableExtra("hero");
        // update views with your new hero object
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathew, thank you very much for the answer - I got it to work using this method and you answered my question perfectly, so I just want to say I appreciate the response.

Comment: Happy I could help.

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putSerializableExtra("thing",thing);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

then in your second activity get the object you just sent with:

```
myThing = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("thing");
```

and make your changes to it. Also makes sure that `getIntent() != null`, otherwise it'll crash.

and send the data back when you close this activity:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putSerializableExtra("result", myThing);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

then in your first activity, you can override this method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        MyObjectType result=data.getSerializableExtra("result");
    }
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //Write your code if there's no result
    }
}
}//onActivityResult
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to make the variables go away after killing the app or something like that, then use a static variable.So, it is accessible in all the classes.

```
public static String OBJ= obj;
```

You can change the variable from any class.But it is not preferable as there might be many race conditions occurring if not properly handled.

If you do not want it to stay even after killing the app, you can use Shared Preferences in android by serializing the object.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(simDetails);

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor e = prefs.edit();
e.putString(key, json);
e.commit();
```

Using preferences is the best way than using a static variable.

Passing intents also can be done but it is not a best way as it takes time to update and this is also prone to race conditions.Best way is Preferences, if not a static variable.Using intent is the last choice I would prefer.